# Trigonometric notation with Initial capital Letter and Italic

Tags: capitalization, italic

How can we make First letter Capital while using trigonometric functions.
eg: \cos (60^\circ) gives simple cos (all in small). What is needed is 'Cos' (with initial capital).
For italics in mactex i used \it but it didn't italicized 'cos' only the number '60'. So how to do that?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). For future reference, it would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.  I don't understand the second part of your question and a MWE would clarify that.

Comment: @PeterGrill ya sure. I will take care of it next time.

Comment: Hey, what happened to your other question?  Also, see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer).

Comment: @PeterGrill. I figured out the problem. I had used the     \begin{equation} twice. It took 2 hrs approx. but solved so deleted.

Comment: Ok, glad that you figured out your issue. But the point of this site is not just to help you with your specific issue, but so that it becomes a source of information for others. If you made that mistake then perhaps others might make a similar mistake in the future so a self answer would have been preferred rather than deletion.

Comment: Oh. Didn't knew that. Thought, that's a silly mistake, so deleted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would highly recommend you ***not*** do this, but you can use `\DeclareMathOperator` to change how the operators are typeset:

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\cos}{Cos}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sin}{Sin}
```

[image]

If you want the operator name in italics you can instead use:

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\cos}{\mathit{Cos}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sin}{\mathit{Sin}}
```

[image]

Again, I would advice you to ***not*** do this. It is not consistent with the normal conventions.

### Notes:

- The `\let` were necessary as we are redefining existing macros, so `\let` the existing definition to `\relax` eliminates the error message.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\let\cos\relax
\let\sin\relax
\DeclareMathOperator{\cos}{Cos}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sin}{Sin}

\begin{document}
$\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta = 1$
\end{document}
```

Comment: @PeterBrill Exactly, since its not consist what could be the other option. My Report is of 70 pages and i have to use trigonometric relations repeatedly. And as per what you have indicated here, i have to use      \DeclareMathOperator{\trigfn}{trigfn} for all the trig. functions i use inreport . Right?

Comment: @ron: Simply use the existing `\cos` and `\sin`. Do _not_ make the first letter capital, and do _not_ use italics for the operator name. Yes, define any new operators that you need using `\DeclareMathOperator`. If you are redefining an existing operator use the `\let\ExistingName\relax` as in the MWE.