# How to print c for cos and s for sin in latex math

Tags: math-mode

I have very long trigonometric formulas in latex. I want to print only `s` instead of printing complete `sin` in the latex document. same for the `cos`. Is there any way ?

Comment: use a multiline equation which makes more sense

Comment: This is very similar in nature to [Trigonometric notation with Initial capital Letter and Italic](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/176844/5764) where you can redefine `\sin` and `\cos` to suit your needs.

Comment: As in the answer at the linked duplicate question, it is _highly_ recommended you _not_ do this.